# How to add more exchange algorithms to Putty SSH session?

Tags: ssh, encryption, putty, ssh-keys

I have a device that accept the following exchange algorithms for SSH connections:

*curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,kexguess2@matt.ucc.asn.au*

I downloaded the latest version of Putty, and it says it supports: *diffie-hellman group exchange, diffie-hellman group 14, diffie-hellman group 1 and RSA-based key exchange*.

I guess it should work because in both configurations I see the diffie-hellman group 14. However, when I try to connect to the device I get the error:

```
Couldn't agree on a key exchange algorithm (available: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,kexguess2@matt.ucc.asn.au)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**That's not the latest version of PuTTY.** ECDH key exchange (including Curve25519) has been supported since 0.68 (February 2017), and [the latest release](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html) as of writing this post is already 0.70 (July 2017).

(The reason DH group-14 doesn't work is because PuTTY only supports it with SHA-1. In current versions, only DH group-exchange is supported with SHA-256.)

Alternatively, you could connect via OpenSSH (standard on Windows 10.1803) or Bitvise [Tunnelier](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-client) (compatible with Windows Vista+); both support all of the above mechanisms.

Comment: could you please provide the links to download the latest version of Putty and OpenSSH? Because I think I donwloaded the latest version of Putty so maybe the installation didn't overwrite the previous settings?

Comment: https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html

Comment: I had the latest version installed already, but also the previous one so, when executing Putty, I was using the older one (without realizing) and didn't work...so I run the latest one and it works! Thank you!